# Docker agent running a jenkins job using wrong npm version

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

### Context :

I'm building a react app using a jenkins pipeline, where the agent is docker agent defined by a Dockerfile in the root of my project, the bug happens in the npm ci stage, where i the console prints warnings about the node version being old ( v12 ), which is wierd because i installed the latest using nvm ( see Dockelfile ).

### The Problem :

In the build logs it says i'm using node v12, but when building the docker image i printed the node version and it was v20.

This is my `Jenkinsfile` :

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile.agent'
        }
    }

    environment {
        TAG="$env.BRANCH_NAME-v$BUILD_NUMBER"
        REGISTRY="foo"
        AWS_REGION="eu-north-1"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build React App') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "npm ci"
                    sh "npm run build"
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Build Docker Image") {
            steps {
                sh "docker build -t staff-manager-admin-ui  ."
            }
        }
        stage('Push to Registry') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'aws-key', variable: 'awsKey'), string(credentialsId: 'aws-secret', variable: 'awsSecret')]) {
                        withEnv(["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$awsKey", "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$awsSecret", "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_REGION"]) {
                            sh "aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $REGISTRY"
                            sh "docker tag staff-manager-admin-ui $REGISTRY:$TAG"
                            sh "docker push $REGISTRY:$TAG"
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the `Dockerfile.agent` :

```
FROM jenkins/agent:latest

USER root

# Install stuff needed for 
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y npm docker awscli default-jdk && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install npm & node
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash \
    && . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install node \
    && node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"

# Add nvm path to bashrc and source it
RUN echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >> $HOME/.bashrc \
    && echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >> $HOME/.bashrc

# Source bashrc to make nvm available in this shell
RUN . $HOME/.bashrc


# Add the commands to fix npm permissions
RUN mkdir -p /.npm
RUN chown -R 1002:1002 /.npm


# USER jenkins
USER 1002:1002
```

Here's a screenshot of the relevant part of the Docker image building

[image]

and then during `npm ci` it says i'm using v12 ?

[image]

### More context :

Repo : https://github.com/HL-Abdallah/staff-manager-admin-ui-cloudsec/tree/acceptation

Full job log :

```
Started by user Abdallah
20:42:02 Connecting to https://api.github.com using github-access
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 58cd4b60dcc9413beca260ed4c601098ab04d2eb
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on gp-agent in /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential github-access
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching without tags
Checking out Revision 58cd4b60dcc9413beca260ed4c601098ab04d2eb (acceptation)
Commit message: "switch to node form --lts"
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/.git # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/HL-Abdallah/staff-manager-admin-ui-cloudsec.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/HL-Abdallah/staff-manager-admin-ui-cloudsec.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.40.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/HL-Abdallah/staff-manager-admin-ui-cloudsec.git +refs/heads/acceptation:refs/remotes/origin/acceptation # timeout=10
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 58cd4b60dcc9413beca260ed4c601098ab04d2eb # timeout=10
 > git rev-list --no-walk 5fa8c7de33f5f562f88479983a05899d360ec4eb # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup)
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t d89fb2028932cbbd1bd5b845c31cdbc6219edd4c -f Dockerfile.agent .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  500.1MB

Step 1/9 : FROM jenkins/agent:latest
 ---> 7ae825327b31
Step 2/9 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e4b66e958c34
Step 3/9 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y npm docker awscli default-jdk &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a8ee6e6ff6de
Step 4/9 : RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash     && . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh     && nvm install node     && node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"
 ---> Running in 4d7be2cfef8e
[91m [0m[91m % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    [0m[91mL[0m[91me[0m[91mf[0m[91mt[0m[91m  Speed

  0     0    0    [0m[91m [0m[91m0[0m[91m    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:[0m[91m-- --:--:--     0[0m[91m
100 15916  100 15916    0     0  98857      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 98857
[0m=> Downloading nvm from git to '/root/.nvm'

=> [91mCloning into '/root/.nvm'...
[0m* (HEAD detached at FETCH_HEAD)
  master
=> Compressing and cleaning up git repository

=> Appending nvm source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Appending bash_completion source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
Downloading and installing node v20.6.1...
[91mDownloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v20.6.1/node-v20.6.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
[0m[91m
####################################[0m[91m                                      50.7%[0m[91m
##########[0m[91m###[0m[91m#[0m[91m##[0m[91m#[0m[91m#[0m[91m#[0m[91m#[0m[91m#[0m[91m################################################### [0m[91m100.0%
[0m[91mComputing checksum with sha256sum
[0m[91mChecksums matched!
[0mNow using node v20.6.1 (npm v9.8.1)
Creating default alias: default -> node (-> v20.6.1 *)
Running Node.js v20.6.1
Removing intermediate container 4d7be2cfef8e
 ---> 79b3a1d0adc5
Step 5/9 : RUN echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >> $HOME/.bashrc     && echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
 ---> Running in d5c5907ade58
Removing intermediate container d5c5907ade58
 ---> 95c5e8081970
Step 6/9 : RUN . $HOME/.bashrc
 ---> Running in d3a90d73d2d4
nvm
Removing intermediate container d3a90d73d2d4
 ---> af3c6dc532dd
Step 7/9 : RUN mkdir -p /.npm
 ---> Running in 0fdf60936204
Removing intermediate container 0fdf60936204
 ---> 57945aa41a9f
Step 8/9 : RUN chown -R 1002:1002 /.npm
 ---> Running in a0cb6cfe91bf
Removing intermediate container a0cb6cfe91bf
 ---> 7a63cd0f10b1
Step 9/9 : USER 1002:1002
 ---> Running in 50723e1eb398
Removing intermediate container 50723e1eb398
 ---> 4fabe0bf14a4
Successfully built 4fabe0bf14a4
Successfully tagged d89fb2028932cbbd1bd5b845c31cdbc6219edd4c:latest
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . d89fb2028932cbbd1bd5b845c31cdbc6219edd4c
.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
gp-agent does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 1002:1002 -w /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation -v /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation:/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation:rw,z -v /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation@tmp:/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** d89fb2028932cbbd1bd5b845c31cdbc6219edd4c cat
$ docker top 12defe4dd2ae7e0342482472c54957b43a2411e7d25cb517180fbd789eba55ea -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build React App)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm ci
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@csstools/postcss-trigonometric-functions@1.0.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14 || >=16' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@faker-js/faker@8.0.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0', npm: '>=6.14.13' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@mui/x-data-grid@6.13.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@mui/x-date-pickers@6.13.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@remix-run/router@1.6.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'postcss-import@15.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'postcss-load-config@4.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-app-polyfill@3.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-dev-utils@12.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-router@6.11.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-router-dom@6.11.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-scripts@5.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'tailwindcss@3.3.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object instead.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated @material-ui/styles@4.11.5: Material UI v4 doesn't receive active development since September 2021. See the guide https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/ to upgrade to v5.
npm WARN deprecated @material-ui/core@4.12.4: Material UI v4 doesn't receive active development since September 2021. See the guide https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/ to upgrade to v5.

added 2135 packages in 2m

257 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm run build

> staff_manager_admin@2.2.0 build
> react-scripts build

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'tapable'
Require stack:
- /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js
- /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ResolverFactory.js
- /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/index.js
- /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js
- /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js
- /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/dist/index.js
- /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:8:60)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js',
    '/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ResolverFactory.js',
    '/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/index.js',
    '/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js',
    '/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js',
    '/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js',
    '/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/dist/index.js',
    '/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js',
    '/home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/jenkins_khaled/jenkins/workspace/Admin_Frontend_React_acceptation
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c react-scripts build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /.npm/_logs/2023-09-09T20_46_34_033Z-debug.log
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build Docker Image)
Stage "Build Docker Image" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Push to Registry)
Stage "Push to Registry" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 12defe4dd2ae7e0342482472c54957b43a2411e7d25cb517180fbd789eba55ea
$ docker rm -f --volumes 12defe4dd2ae7e0342482472c54957b43a2411e7d25cb517180fbd789eba55ea
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple `RUN` commands in your `Dockerfile`, each of them is run in an independent process. So anything set in the environment of one `RUN` command is not persisted in the environment of next `RUN` command.

This is actually required because `nvm` sets the `NODE_VERSION` in the environment variable to determine the default version to use.

There are a couple of ways to solve this:

1. You can use a node version specific base image for your `Dockerfile`. That way, you wont even need `nvm`. Check out some of the images here: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/ (eg: `20-bullseye-slim`)
2. You can use the `ENV` command to persist the environment variables that `nvm` uses, like `NVM_DIR`, `NODE_PATH`, `NODE_VERSION` and `PATH`.

```
# Create the directory to store nvm
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/nvm

# export this env var
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm

# set the node version you want here
ENV NODE_VERSION v20.6.1

# download nvm
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash

RUN /bin/bash -c "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm use --delete-prefix $NODE_VERSION"

# persist the paths that nvm normally does
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/bin
ENV PATH $NODE_PATH:$PATH

RUN node -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by applying these changes to the Dockerfile.agent

```
FROM jenkins/agent:latest

USER root

# Install stuff needed for building & deploying
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y docker awscli default-jdk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    npm
RUN npm install npm@latest -g && \
    npm install n -g && \
    n latest

# Add the commands to fix npm permissions
RUN mkdir -p /.npm
RUN chown -R 1002:1002 /.npm
USER 1002:1002
```